# Deserialize XML nested collections in C#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, deserialization, nested-lists

So I am having trouble when deserializing my XML that has nested collections in it. I was able to deserialize it before the nested collection(Grades) was added but have not been able to since. Any help would be great!

Below is what the XML is serialized as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListOfPlayers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Player>
    <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
    <LastName>Jordan</LastName>
    <EmailAddress>jordanm@seattleu.edu</EmailAddress>
    <PhoneNumber>206-227-6000</PhoneNumber>
    <NumberOfExtraTeamsWillingToFill>2</NumberOfExtraTeamsWillingToFill>
    <IsActive>true</IsActive>
    <InactiveReason />
    <PlayerNotes />
    <GradesCurrentlyEnrolled>
      <Grades>First</Grades>
      <Grades>Second</Grades>
    </GradesCurrentlyEnrolled>
    </Player>
<Player>
    <FirstName>Magic</FirstName>
    <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
    <EmailAddress>johnsonm@seattleu.edu</EmailAddress>
    <PhoneNumber>206-227-6000</PhoneNumber>
    <NumberOfExtraTeamsWillingToFill>3</NumberOfExtraTeamsWillingToFill>
    <IsActive>true</IsActive>
    <InactiveReason />
    <PlayerNotes>Has a new baby</PlayerNotes>
    <GradesCurrentlyEnrolled>
      <Grades>Sixth</Grades>
      <Grades>Eighth</Grades>
    </GradesCurrentlyEnrolled>
    </Player>
</ListOfPlayers>
```

Here is the Code for Player Class:

```
 public class Player : ModelBase
    {
    public Player()
    {
        FirstName = "";
        LastName = "";
        PhoneNumber = "";
        EmailAddress = "";
        NumberOfExtraTeamsWillingToFill = 0;
        IsActive = true;
        InactiveReason = "";
        PlayerNotes = "";
        GradesCurrentlyEnrolled = new ListOfGrades();
    }

    public Player(string firstName, string lastName, string phoneNumber, string emailAddress, int numberOfExtraTeamsWillingToFill,
        bool isActive, string inactiveReason, ListOfGrades gradesCurrentlyEnrolled, string playerNotes)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        EmailAddress = emailAddress;
        NumberOfExtraTeamsWillingToFill = numberOfExtraTeamsWillingToFill;
        IsActive = isActive;
        InactiveReason = inactiveReason;
        PlayerNotes = playerNotes;
        GradesCurrentlyEnrolled = gradesCurrentlyEnrolled;
    }

    // IsPlayerFloating
    public bool IsPlayerFloating
    {
        get
        {
            return (GradesCurrentlyEnrolled.Count == 0);
        }
    }

    // GradesCurrentlyEnrolled
    private ListOfGrades _gradesCurrentlyEnrolled;
    public ListOfGrades GradesCurrentlyEnrolled
    {
        get { return _gradesCurrentlyEnrolled; }
        set { _gradesCurrentlyEnrolled = value;}         //SendPropertyChanged("GradesCurrentlyEnrolled"); }
    }

}
```

And this is the code for Serializing and deserializing:

```
       private void LoadAllPlayers()
    {
        ListOfPlayer _playersForSerial;
        Player testPlayer;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Player));

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
        testPlayer = (Player)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();

        Players.Add(new PlayerViewModel(testPlayer));

        foreach (Player pv in _playersForSerial)
        {
            Players.Add(new PlayerViewModel());
        }

    }

    public void SaveAllPlayers()
    {
        ListOfPlayer _playersForSerial = new ListOfPlayer();

        //Creates a list of Players fromt eh ViewModels
        foreach (PlayerViewModel pv in Players)
        {
            _playersForSerial.Add(pv.GetPlayer);

        }

        // Note that only the collection is serialized -- not the 
        // CollectionName or any other public property of the class.
        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListOfPlayer));
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
        x.Serialize(writer, _playersForSerial);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Also here is the code for the collections:

```
[XmlRootAttribute("ListOfPlayers")]
public class ListOfPlayer : ObservableCollection<Player>
{
}

[XmlRoot("GradesList")]
public class ListOfGrades : List<Grades>
{
}
```

Also Grades is an enum:

```
public enum Grades
{
    PreK,
    K,
    First,
    Second,
    Third,
    Fourth,
    Fifth,
    Sixth,
    Seventh,
    Eighth
}
```

Thanks again! Sorry for all the information.

Comment: Keep the XMLRoot tag of ListOfGrades same as the property name in Players class. It will work. Currently, ListOfGrades is lookin fr root node "GradesList" which does not exist but "GradesCurrentlyEnrolled" is present which is the name of the property.
Avoid giving XMlRoot to ListOfGrades, it might solve the problem

Comment: It seems that no matter what the ListOfGrades' XMLRoot is it still gives me a XamlParseException when I try and deserialize. When I step through it always break at: 

testPlayer = (Player)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

Answer (score 0):

You should provide information about additional types to xmlSerializer like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Player),new []{typeof(ListOfGrades)});
```

Comment: This generates an InvalidOperationException when it tries to serialize the Players.